Pytorch lightning model running issue on rtx 4090 gpu
I have a pytorch lightning GAN model which is running on google colab tesla t4 gpu without any problem. But when I run the same model on rtx 4090 gpu in a local datacenter the code stalls on backward step of discriminator and nothing happens.
this is the training function
def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):

        images, future_images = batch
        images = images.float()
        future_images = future_images.float()

        self.global_iteration += 1
        g_opt, d_opt = self.optimizers()
        ##########################
        # Optimize Discriminator #
        ##########################
        # Two discriminator steps per generator step

        for _ in range(2):

            d_opt.zero_grad()
            predictions = self(images)

            generated_sequence = torch.cat([images, predictions], dim=1)
            real_sequence = torch.cat([images, future_images], dim=1)

            concatenated_inputs = torch.cat([real_sequence, generated_sequence], dim=0)

            concatenated_outputs = self.discriminator(concatenated_inputs)

            score_real, score_generated = torch.split(
                concatenated_outputs, [real_sequence.shape[0], generated_sequence.shape[0]], dim=0
            )
            score_real_spatial, score_real_temporal = torch.split(score_real, 1, dim=1)
            score_generated_spatial, score_generated_temporal = torch.split(
                score_generated, 1, dim=1
            )

            discriminator_loss = loss_hinge_disc(
                score_generated_spatial, score_real_spatial
            ) + loss_hinge_disc(score_generated_temporal, score_real_temporal)

            self.manual_backward(discriminator_loss)

            d_opt.step()

        ######################
        # Optimize Generator #
        ######################
        predictions = [self(images) for _ in range(self.generation_steps)]
        grid_cell_reg = grid_cell_regularizer(torch.stack(predictions, dim=0), future_images)

        generated_sequence = [torch.cat([images, x], dim=1) for x in predictions]
        real_sequence = torch.cat([images, future_images], dim=1)
        
        generated_scores = []
        for g_seq in generated_sequence:
            concatenated_inputs = torch.cat([real_sequence, g_seq], dim=0)
            concatenated_outputs = self.discriminator(concatenated_inputs)

            score_real, score_generated = torch.split(
                concatenated_outputs, [real_sequence.shape[0], g_seq.shape[0]], dim=0
            )
            generated_scores.append(score_generated)
        generator_disc_loss = loss_hinge_gen(torch.cat(generated_scores, dim=0))
        generator_loss = generator_disc_loss + self.grid_lambda * grid_cell_reg
        g_opt.zero_grad()
        self.manual_backward(generator_loss)
        g_opt.step()

the code stalls on self.manual_backward(discriminator_loss)
I tried changing the batch size and even I ran the code on a rtx 3080 gpu in same datacenter but I faced the same problem. but when I ran it on cpu there where no problem.

Is it possible it's just taking more time on the those GPUs?

no i waited for more than 2 hours but the code execution did not proceeded further. on colab whole running process fore one epoch is done in about 1:20 hour.
this problem happens at first iteration and the model can not do anything more.
moreover i must mention that i tested cpu too and the code ran properly.

Is this an issue with any gpu from your datacenter ?

I tried rtx 4090 and 3080 gpus in this datacenter and none of them worked
